# Splitting text in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing some script which capture data from web site and save them into DB. Some of datas are merged and I need to split them. I have sth like this

```
Endokrynologia (bez st.),Położnictwo i ginekologia (II st.)
```

So i need to get:

```
Endokrynologia (bez st.)
Położnictwo i ginekologia (II st.)
```

So i wrote some code in python:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: utf-8

import MySQLdb as mdb
from lxml import html, etree
import urllib
import sys
import re

Nr = 17268
Link = "http://rpwdl.csioz.gov.pl/rpz/druk/wyswietlKsiegaServletPub?idKsiega="

sock = urllib.urlopen(Link+str(Nr))  
htmlSource = sock.read()                             
sock.close()
root = etree.HTML(htmlSource)
result = etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, method="html")
Spec = etree.XPath("string(//html/body/div/table[2]/tr[18]/td[2]/text())")
Specjalizacja = Spec(root)
if re.search(r'(,)\b', Specjalizacja):
    text = Specjalizacja.split()
    print text[0]
    print text[1]
```

and i get:

```
Endokrynologia
(bez
```

what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: why not just just the BIF `split(',')`?

Answer (score 0):

you would try to replace

```
text = Specjalizacja.split()
```

with

```
text = Specjalizacja.split(',')
```

Don't know whether that would fix your problem.

Comment: I don't know why I did not write .split(',')